# Spring Integration block flow having Loop and multiple HTTP and async SQS

Tags: spring-integration

I have a flow that

```
1. Starts with a config map -> MainGateway.start(configMap) -> void
2. Splits map into multiple messages per entry
3. For every config entry do the following using an orchestrator java class:
   BEGIN LOOP (offset and limit)
      Data d = HTTPGateway.getData();
      PublishGateway.sendMessage(d); -> Send to 2 SQS queues    
   END LOOP
```

**Requirement**
I have to schedule this flow via cron. One option is to provide an HTTP endpoint that will start the flow. But then the second HTTP request should wait/timeout/error until the first is complete.

**Question**
I was looking at barrier to implement blocking for the flow thread until it completes and have only a single thread http processor, so at one time only 1 request is processed and I can know when the flow is complete. (The LOOP ends for all config entry objects and all messages to SQS are acked). How can I achieve this? I have a loop and am using pub-sub channel with executors for parallel configs and parallel SQS dispatch.

I have trimmed down the `XML config` below for clarity.

```
   <!-- Bring in list of Configs to process -->
    <int:gateway service-interface="Gateway"
                 default-request-channel="configListChannel" />

    <int:chain input-channel="configListChannel" output-channel="configChannel">
        <!-- Split the list to one instance of config per message -->
        <int:splitter/>
        <int:filter expression="payload.enablePolling" />
    </int:chain>

    <!-- Manually orchestrate a loop to query a system as per config and publish messages to SQS -->
    <bean class="Orchestrator" id="orchestrator" />
    <int:service-activator ref="orchestrator" method="getData" input-channel="configChannel" />

    <!-- The flow from this point onwards is triggered inside a loop controlled by the Orchestrator
         The following Gateway calls are inside Orchestrators loop -->

    <!-- Create a Http request from the Orchestrator using a Gateway -->
    <int:gateway service-interface="HttpGateway">
        <int:method name="getData"
                    request-channel="requestChannel"
                    payload-expression="#args[0]">
        </int:method>
    </int:gateway>

    <!-- Transform request object to json and invoke Http endpoint -->
    <int:chain input-channel="requestChannel" id="httpRequestChain">
        <int:object-to-json-transformer />
        <int-http:outbound-gateway url-expression="headers['config'].url"
                                   http-method="POST"
                                   expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
        />
    </int:chain>

    <!-- Publish Messages to Outbound Gateway -->
    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="5" />
    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="publishChannel" task-executor="executor" />
    <int:gateway service-interface="PublishGateway" >
        <int:method name="publishToOutbound" payload-expression="#args[0]" request-channel="publishChannel" />
    </int:gateway>


    <!-- Route to System A SQS with transformations (omitted here)-->
    <int-aws:sqs-outbound-channel-adapter sqs="amazonSQS" channel="publishChannel" queue="system-a-queue" success-channel="successChannel" failure-channel="errorChannel"/>

    <!-- Route to System B SQS with transformations (omitted here)-->
    <int-aws:sqs-outbound-channel-adapter sqs="amazonSQS" channel="publishChannel" queue="system-b-queue" success-channel="successChannel" failure-channel="errorChannel"/>

    <int:logging-channel-adapter logger-name="sqsCallbackLogger" log-full-message="true" channel="successChannel" />
```

In the meanwhile, I am trying to adapt the A B C barrier example from `spring-integration-samples` to my use case.

Comment: Let me ask you a couple questions: You probably may have more than two requests. And the next one indeed should wait for the previous. You want to make only `publishChannel` subscribers in parallel. Everything else has to be really one by one. Correct me what I missed.

Comment: The whole flow starting with `configListChannel` and ending with 2 SQS outbound messages is a like a job that needs to run say every 10 mns. To trigger this flow, I am thinking to have a HTTP endpoint. If the HTTP endpoints triggered while the flow is already running the request should time/error out, implies that I need to keep a track of when the flow ends. Its like I need a barrier starting on the `configListChannel` (may be the even before on the HTTP inbound that I will add) and the barrier should release when LOOP ends for all configs (pub-sub:configChannel) in success acks from 2 SQS.

Comment: Alternatively, since an HTTP Gateway always returns may be I could use a HTTP Gateway with Ack aggregator for SQS that returns a composite json response of SQS message Ids for all messages and error messages like a report of the execution. I need to try this though, than I guess barrier is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out in your comment, an `aggregator` approach could be used in your solution.

This way you aggregated results of those parallel SQS requests and wait for an aggregation reply in the original requestor. This way it is really going to be blocked even if internals of your flow still concurrent. You call a gateway and the reply for it is going to be from the aggregator.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that