# @EnableConfigurationProperties(MyConfig.class) generated bean name does not work in spring-integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I have a config class with `@ConfigurationProperties` as follows. I am able to populate `systemConfigMap` from application.yaml in the `MyConfig` class as seen below

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-config")
@ConstructorBinding
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyConfig {

    /**
     * A Configuration Map of multiple Systems
     */
    private Map<String, SystemConfig> systemConfigMap;
    
}
```

the main class as

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyConfig.class)
public class SpringApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the generated bean name is `my-config-a.b.c.config.MyConfig`, which I am not able to use in `payload-expression` on `spring integration http inbound gateway`, I guess since it has "-" in it.

How can I specify the bean name for the generated bean `MyConfig`?

**EDIT : HTTP Gateway Config**

```
 <int:channel id="myConfigListChannel" />
 <int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="myConfigListChannel"
                              path="/data"
                              error-channel="errorChannel"
                              supported-methods="GET"
                              payload-expression="@my-config-a.b.c.config.MyConfig.getSystemConfigMap().values()"
    />
```

I want to load the `systemConfigMap` values when `/data` is requested to start processing the flow.

Comment: Show, please, how do you use it in that expression? And what is the goal to use it at all in the expression like that?

Comment: Added via EDIT to the question. I want to trigger the flow which starts by reading `systemConfigMap` values, externally hence added an `HTTP Inbound Gateway` only to trigger the flow and return the results. Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63598100/spring-integration-block-flow-having-loop-and-multiple-http-and-async-sqs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to use a complex bean id like yours `my-config-a.b.c.config.MyConfig` in the SpEL expression, you need to wrap it into the literal. Otherwise it understands an id until the first `.` which is treat as method/property reference to evaluate on a possible bean evaluate before.
So, it tries to find a bean like `my-config-a` and then tries to get access to its `b` property, which is fully false in your case.

To fix your problem you need to do like this:

```
 payload-expression="@'my-config-a.b.c.config.MyConfig'.systemConfigMap.values()"
```

Another trick would be like your `MyConfig` injection into some bean with really meaningful bean name and use that one from the expression as a delegate.

Comment: Thank you, that works! I did try adding the single quotes earlier but Intellij showed error, so did not run the app to test, damn. Sorry for the trouble, thanks again !

Comment: Or you can just add `MyConfig` as a `@Bean` (or `<bean/>`) instead of adding it to `@EnableConfigurationProperties`.